# Facebook javascript login window

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using Javascript SDK for Facebook, you can do a

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('Logged out.');
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

My problem is that by using this, it opens a popup window, which some of the browsers kills it. How can I do this in another way? and inside div? or an overlay something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call FB.login, or any method which prompts a pop up, as a direct result of the user clicking something. Then the pop ups will not be blocked. If you try to run it on page load or at a random time, it will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, you can only do it in whatever way the FB api will let you do it.

You could try reverse-engineering its mechanism, but it'll break as soon as facebook changes anything in its platform.